# is File.WriteAllBytes(String, Byte[]) Method can be used to save images

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to save a base64 image to my directory here is the code.  Actually, I am getting the file in my directory but when I open it displays a format error

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult MultiFileUploader(string[] base64image)
{
   if (base64image.Length <= 0)
      return Content("Error");
   for (int i = 0; i < base64image.Length; i++)
   {
      String path = Server.MapPath("~/assets/images/Test/"); //Path

      //Check if directory exist
      if (!Directory.Exists(path))
      {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(path); //Create directory if it doesn't exist
      }
      var randomFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + ".png";
           
      //set the image path
      string imgPath = Path.Combine(path, randomFileName);
      var t = base64image[i].Substring(23);  // remove data:image/png;base64,
      byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(t);
      string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
      byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
      //byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ImgStr);

      System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imgPath, bytes);
           
   }

   string status = "error";
   try
   {                
      if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
      {
         status = "success";
      }
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      throw;
   }
   return Content(status);
}
```

Comment: You are destroying your image at `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(t)`. `WriteAllBytes` has nothing to do with it. You are supposed to only do `byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t);`

Comment: This could be have been solved by [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging): first I extract the base64 string, then I convert the base64 string to a byte array, then I convert the byte array to a base64 string, then I convert the base64 string to a byte array, wait... what am I doing here...

Comment: Instead of blindly removing the first 23 chars, find the (first) comma and remove until there (could it possibly be "image/jpeg"?)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing right, some real debugging would also not hurt. Easy to watch in a debugger: how does base64image string look like at first, does t contain what I expect it to contain.... People should leran how to use a debugger instead of going to SO when something doesn't work.

Comment: @GSergis thanks I fixed that, removed that encoding statement, directly used byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t); as you mentioned thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, thanks for your vote, I am a beginner actually.
here is how I fixed it.

**Controller Action**

```
string t = base64image[i].Substring(SubChar);  // remove data:image/png;base64,
                    string t2 = t.Remove(t.Length - 1, 1);//extra quotation mark was there in end of string
                    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(t2);
                    Image image;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }                    
                    image.Save(imgPath, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert from base64 to binary data you just need to call FromBase64String.
In your code you are messing up your data by doing this:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(t);
b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
```

conversion from your `t` variable to byte array only needs `Convert.FromBase64String(t);`

Also be careful when stripping "data:image/png;base64,": Substring parameter is zero-based, so the 23rd character (the first you need) actually has index 22 starting from 0.

This is how you can save a base64 png:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var data_b64 = "data:image/png:base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN..."; // your initial data

        var png_b64 = data_b64.Substring(22); // extract only base64 part.

        var png_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(png_b64); // Convert FROM base64 To bytes

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\path\to\file.png", png_bytes); // save your file
    }
```